# Geometric invariant theory Affine Quotients

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, group-schemes

Let $V=Spec(R[V])$ an affine variey and $G$ a linear reductive group action on $V$. (I'm not sure if the linear reductive condition is neccessary for the question).

According to [GIT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_invariant_theory) the "quotient" $V/G=Spec(R[V]^G)$ parametrizes closed orbits.

My question is if it can be happen that $V/G$ has more than one (closed) singleton-orbits. Obviously the "$0$-point" is a one-point orbit. Could there also exist another such one-point orbit?

If the answer is yes, then can $V/G$ be even a discrete or finite set?

I we futhermore add extra assumptions on $V$ from topological nature (irreducibility, reduceness,...). What does $V/G$ inherit?

Comment: With no assumptions on $V$, sure - take $V$ as the disjoint union of orbits. Your reference to the "$0$-point" makes me think that there may be assumptions here you haven't stated. If that's the case, please improve your question.

Comment: @KReiser: my question tend to topological restrictions the for space $X/G$ depending on the given (Zariski)-topology on $V$ especially concerning irreducibility. So in kind of let $P$ be a topological property of $V$. Does $V/G$ inherit it?

Comment: It does not parametrize orbites but closed orbits. For example you can look at $GL_n$ acting on $M_n$ by conjugation.

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet: yes of course, I forgot to mention it. So my question refers in the whole thread to closed orbits

Comment: The natural morphism $V \to V/G$ is surjective so if $V$ is irreducible then $V/G$ is so. However $V/G$ can be irreducible even though $V$ was not reducible. I think $V/G$ is never discrete unless very degenerate case.